# Desktop bigger then screen after nvidia drivers installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I got problems with nvidia drivers, after I installed them and reboot my desktop is to big for my screen. I can only see some piece of the background.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Resetting_an_out-of-range_resolution) you can use following options to set your screen resolution to correct value:

1. **Resetting an out-of-range resolution**
   If you set a resolution inappropriate for your monitor in the Screen Resolution GUI tool, you can reset it from a terminal by running:

   ```
   $ rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
   ```
2. **Dynamically testing different resolutions**
   You can either use the Screen Resolution GUI tool to experiment with different resolutions, or the more powerful xrandr command-line tool. Without parameters, xrandr shows you the names of different outputs available on your system (LVDS, VGA-0, etc.) and resolutions available on each:

   ```
   $ xrandr
   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1400 x 1050, maximum 1400 x 1400
   VGA disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   LVDS connected 1400x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 286mm x 214mm
      1400x1050      60.0*+   50.0  
   [...]
   ```

   You can direct xrandr to set a different resolution like this:

   ```
   $ xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768
   $ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768
   ```

   The refresh rate may also be changed, either at the same time or independently:

   ```
   $ xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768 --rate 75
   $ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768 --rate 60
   ```

### Setting xrandr changes persistently

There are several ways to make xrandr customizations permanent from session to session: a) .xprofile, b) kdm/gdm, c) xorg.conf. Each of these mechanisms will be discussed in turn.

**Setting xrandr commands in .xprofile**

A user's ~/.xprofile file is executed on Xorg startup if it exists and is executable. You can copy and paste xrandr command line strings into this file so they're executed when you log in. For example:

```
$ xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 800x600
```

There are two disadvantages to using .xprofile for xrandr settings. First, it occurs fairly late in the startup process, so you'll see some resolution resizing during the initial screen draw; in some cases panel windows may resize improperly as a result. Second, as this is a per-user setting, it won't affect the resolutions of other users, nor will it alter the resolution on the login screen.

**Setting xrandr commands in kdm/gdm startup scripts**

Both KDM and GDM have startup scripts that are executed when X is initiated. For GDM, these are in /etc/gdm/ , while for KDM this is done at /etc/kde4/kdm/Xsetup. In either case, you can paste in an xrandr command line string into one of these scripts. For GDM, try putting them right before

```
initctl -q emit login-session-start DISPLAY_MANAGER=gdm
```

in /etc/gdm/Init/Default.

This process requires root access and mucking around in system config files, but will take effect earlier in the startup process than using .xprofile, and will apply to all users including the login screen.

**Setting resolution changes in xorg.conf**

While xorg.conf is largely empty these days, it can still be used for setting up resolutions. For example:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "External DVI"
    Modeline        "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
    Option          "PreferredMode" "1280x1024_60.00"
EndSection
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "ATI Technologies, Inc. M22 [Radeon Mobility M300]"
    Driver          "ati"
    Option          "Monitor-DVI-0" "External DVI"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Primary Screen"
    Device          "ATI Technologies, Inc. M22 [Radeon Mobility M300]"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth           24
        Modes   "1280x1024" "1024x768" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "Default Layout"
        Screen          "Primary Screen"
EndSection
```

See man xorg.conf for full details on how to craft an xorg.conf file.